# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TimeoutError: Navigation timeout of 30000 ms exceeded

Tags: puppeteer

I have a problem I can't use Puppeteer. I even tried a basic example from the doc.
But I'm getting this error :

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TimeoutError: Navigation timeout of
> 30000 ms exceeded

I have searched few solutions like disabling the timeout, but it's not working.

I am on Windows using WSL: Ubuntu

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({args: [
    '--no-sandbox',
  ]});
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://news.ycombinator.com', {
    waitUntil: 'networkidle2',
  });
  await page.pdf({ path: 'hn.pdf', format: 'a4' });

  await browser.close();
})();
```

If you have some tips to help me !
Thank you !

Comment: Could you try adding `headless: false` to the `puppeteer.launch` options? That might reveal the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding `headless` mode and see if it works. I did and it worked for me.

```
//using ES6 (doesn't matter)
import { launch } from "puppeteer";

(async () => {
  const browser = await launch({
    args: ["--no-sandbox"],
    headless: true,
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto("https://news.ycombinator.com", {
    waitUntil: "networkidle2",
  });
  await page.pdf({ path: "hn.pdf", format: "a4" });

  await browser.close();
})();
```

[image: hn.pdf image on terminal and vscode preview]